# Invalid url in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to develop my own angularjs directive to show a webcam (twitcam or youtube) everywhere : https://github.com/batphil/angular-streamlist

I have a problem for show twitcams webcams.

I construc url in the directive like that :

```
    $scope.trustUrl = function(domain, id) {
        if (domain == 'twitcam') {
            var urlInjected = 'http://static.livestream.com/grid/LSPlayer.swf?hash=' + id + '?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1';
            //console.log('url is : ' + urlInjected);
        } else if (domain == 'youtube') {
            var urlInjected = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1';
            //console.log('url is : ' + urlInjected);
        }

        var urlFormated = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(urlInjected);
        console.log('urlFormated is : ' + urlFormated);

        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(urlInjected);
    }
```

And the html :

```
<object id="twitcamPlayer" width="{{ getWidth(stream_type) }}" height="{{ getHeight(stream_type) }}" classid="{{stream_webcam.webcam_object}}">
    <param name="movie" value="{{ trustUrl(stream_webcam.webcam_domain, stream_webcam.webcam_id) }}"/>
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="window"/>
    <embed name="twitcamPlayer" src="{{ trustUrl(stream_webcam.webcam_domain, stream_webcam.webcam_id) }}" allowFullScreen="false" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="{{ getWidth(stream_type) }}" height="{{ getHeight(stream_type) }}" wmode="window" ></embed>
</object>
```

I don't understand why, but with twitcam, url are not correctly maked, like this : `GET domain-used.com/%7B%7B%20trustUrl(stream_webcam.webcam_domain,%20stream_webcam.webcam_id)%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

I try to show in console urls and i can see differences in the console :

[image]

youtube links have a border under, but not livestream, so youtube links are links and twticam links are strings ?

Other question: you can see in console that the console.log are so many, and repeated, it's normal ?

Comment: The LiveStream ones have two `?`s in them, and are therefore not valid links: `http://.../LSPlayer.swf?hash=35453745?autoplay=...` Also, the `&amp;` in the urls will probably break things in both YouTube and LiveStream.

Comment: No, youtube videos are correctly showed. and when i put `http://static.livestream.com/grid/LSPlayer.swf?hash=ge3fb?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1` manually, it's good. It's the good codes from youtube and twitcam. `&amp;` is for to be html valid.

Comment: EDIT :  you're right, in livestream link, i replace the second `?` with `&amp;` , but it's just typo mistake, the problem is even present, nothing changed.

Comment: I think I see the problem now. try replacing `src="{{ trustUrl(stream_webcam.webcam_domain, stream_webcam.webcam_id) }}"` with `ng-src="trustUrl(stream_webcam.webcam_domain, stream_webcam.webcam_id)"`

Comment: EDIT: Also, the thing will re-run every time the scope refreshes itself, hence all the console logs. Every time you update something in the scope, it basically re-evaluates all the scope functions.

Comment: Nothing change when i try ng-src.

Comment: Can you try using
`var urlInjected = decodeURIComponent('http://static.livestream.com/grid/LSPlayer.swf?hash=' + id + '?autoplay=1&amp;autohide=1')`

Comment: Sorry about that. Use `ng-src` with the `{{...}}`. As in: `ng-src="{{ trustUrl(stream_webcam.webcam_domain, stream_webcam.webcam_id) }}"`

Comment: always same result :( I tried to put manually the return `return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://static.livestream.com/grid/LSPlayer.swf?hash=ge9m8&amp;autoplay=true');` and it's show again the error `GET my-domain.com/%7B%7B%20trustUrl(stream_webcam.webcam_domain,%20stream_webcam.webcam_id)%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)` , so it's a view problem ? why ? because it's a embed tag ? the youtube view is a `src` too but there is no problem.

Comment: I just discover this issue : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1352 seems there is no solution

Comment: It's very difficult, i have a webchat application, and i can't refresh/add/remove the distant datas for twitcam :/ i can't say to users "refresh page, and see new webcams of others members". there is no other way ?

Comment: I made a demo, no directive, just test for twitcam http://www.strapontins.org/angucam/index.html

Comment: @JoDiii: Creating a reproduction of the issue in JSFiddle/Plnkr/CodePen/etc would definitely help get better feedback.